# Why Ardor does not use Maven?

Tags: development, compiling, ardor, source-code

Are there some reasons why maven and standard maven directory layout are not used in Ardor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several reasons for this:

1. We don't want a dependency management tool to automatically download software from the web. There is always a risk of some backdoor inserted by someone malicious in case we do not manually verify each 3rd party component.
2. We would like to keep the build scripts as simple and low level as possible to maintain full control of the build output. Specifically, we would like to make sure the build is 100% reproducible from source so that anyone can rebuild it to make sure the published source code is the one used to build the published binaries.
3. We don't particularly like Maven.